# How to combine rows in two data frames given a certain condition in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have these two data frames called:

table1

```
+---------+------------+------+
|  Animal |    Owner   |count1|
+---------+------------+------+
|    Cat  |     Bob    |   3  |
|    Fish |    Jerry   |   2  |
|    Dog  |     Bob    |   2  |
|  Turtle |     Joe    |   5  |
+---------+------------+------+
```

table2

```
+---------+------------+------+
|  Animal |    Owner   |count2|
+---------+------------+------+
|    Cat  |     Bob    |   2  |
|    Fish |     Jerry  |   1  |
|    Dog  |     Bob    |   3  |
|   Snake |     Kim    |   6  |
+---------+------------+------+
```

I am trying to combine both of these data frames in a way, such that the new data frame below would contain rows

- that appear in either 'table1' or table2'
- where distinct rows found in both tables contain count values that are greater in 'table2' than in 'table1'

This is the expected output data frame I want to produce.

```
+---------+------------+------+------+
|  Animal |   Owner    |count1|count2|
+---------+------------+------+------+
|   Dog   |     Bob    |   2  |   3  |
|  Turtle |     Joe    |   5  | null |
|   Snake |     Kim    | null |   6  |
+---------+------------+------+------+
```

Rows that appear in 'table1' and not in 'table2' (or in 'table2' and not in 'table1') can have their count values be 'null'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark Try full join with `filter` condition

```
scala> var t1 = Seq(("Cat","Bob",3),  ("Fish" ,"Jerry" ,2),  ("Dog"  ,    "Bob",2),  ("Turtle" ,"Joe",5)).toDF("Animal","Owner","count1")

scala> var t2 = Seq(("Cat", "Bob",2),("Fish","Jerry",1),("Dog" ,"Bob",3),("Snake","Kim",6)).toDF("Animal","Owner","count2")
```

In dataframe t1(table1) and t2(table2) applying `full join` with keeping null rows of both count columns from tables.

```
scala> t2.join(t1,Seq("Animal","Owner"),"full").filter(col("count2")>col("count1") || col("count2").isNull || col("count1").isNull).show
+------+-----+------+------+
|Animal|Owner|count2|count1|
+------+-----+------+------+
|   Dog|  Bob|     3|     2|
| Snake|  Kim|     6|  null|
|Turtle|  Joe|  null|     5|
+------+-----+------+------+
```